# How to get unpersonalized results in Google?

Tags: google-search

I want to see a "normal" SERP, not affected by Google's custom search algorithms. I know that Google algorithms are pervasive (web history, mail, chat, cooky, IP...).

What can I do to see "normal" results, as if I was born today?
Is there an online service giving this output?

Comment: See [Search and browse privately - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/4540094?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't Google but it queries the Google servers for results:
https://startpage.com/
This search engine does not store any personally identifiable information.

Another thing you can do is disable javascript when using Google, this should reduce the amount of guessing it does.

I haven't tested it myself but [this plugin](http://yoast.com/tools/seo/disable-personalized-search-plugin/) claims to do it for you.

Comment: https://startpage.com/  is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

To see a normal SERP, you can access Google without signing in with a Google Account.

If you're concerned about privacy, use a search engine like [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/privacy.html)

Answer (score 3):

Search in incognito mode / private mode, the session for this mode is not shared and the history is deleted on close.

On Firefox open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> shortcut,
on Chrome open it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The browser extension, [**Searchonymous**](https://github.com/MorbZ/Searchonymous) ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/searchonymous/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/searchonymous/onhfdppooafpnnigbmnpnnjmbajggekc?hl=en)) can allow this.

> Search anonymously on Google, while keeping your search preferences and stay logged in on services such as Youtube, Gmail, etc.
>
> Searchonymous helps to prevent your Google searches from tracking by Google or the NSA. When installed no tracking cookies are sent to Google while searching. This is done by blocking certain Google cookies (such as the PREF-ID) or generating randomized ones (which are worthless for tracking). Other cookies that just contain your search preferences will be allowed, so your preferences are preserved. You will stay logged in on other Google services such as Youtube or Gmail. It also removes ads and clutter from the Google main page that is normally shown when cookies are disabled.
>
> Please note that even if no tracking cookies are sent the NSA can possibly try other techniques to track you (e.g. by IP or browser headers) but these are not as accurate as tracking IDs that are sent on every search.